# Apply tidyr::separate over multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, tidyr

I would like to iterate over columns in a dataframe and split them into the based on a separator. I am using `tidyr::separate`, which works when I do one column at a time.

For example:

```
df<- data.frame(a = c("5312,2020,1212"), b = c("345,982,284"))

df <- separate(data = df, col = "a", 
                         into = paste("a", c("col1", "col2", "col3"), 
                                      sep = "_"), sep = ",")
```

Returns:

```
  a_col1 a_col2 a_col3           b
1   5312   2020   1212 345,982,284
```

When I try to execute the same operation over each column of `df` R returns an error

For example I used this for loop:

```
for(col in names(df)){
    df <- separate(data = df, col = col, 
into = paste(col, c("col1", "col2", "col3), 
sep = "_"), sep = ",")
    }
```

I was expecting to get the following output:

```
  a_col1 a_col2 a_col3 b_col1 b_col2 b_col3
1   5312   2020   1212    345    982    284
```

However R returns this error:

```
Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there another way to apply `tidyr::separate` over multiple columns in a data frame?

Comment: `df %>% gather() %>% separate_rows(value) %>% mutate(key = paste0(key, '_col', 1:3)) %>% spread(key, value)`, but that's really not simpler than calling `separate` twice.

Comment: ...or you can fix your original with the SE `separate_`, i.e. `for(name in names(df)) df <- separate_(df, name, into = paste0(name, '_col', 1:3))`, but that style makes me very uneasy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could feed a customized `separate_()` call into `Reduce()`.

```
sep <- function(...) {
    dots <- list(...)
    n <- stringr::str_count(dots[[1]][[dots[[2]]]], "\\d+")
    separate_(..., into = sprintf("%s_col%d", dots[[2]], 1:n))
}

df %>% Reduce(f = sep, x = c("a", "b"))
#   a_col_1 a_col_2 a_col_3 b_col_1 b_col_2 b_col_3
# 1    5312    2020    1212     345     982     284
```

Otherwise, `cSplit` will do it too.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, names(df))
#     a_1  a_2  a_3 b_1 b_2 b_3
# 1: 5312 2020 1212 345 982 284
```

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit` is useful. However, the `sep` function is a bit confusing, it works for given `df` but if scaling up to larger and different data frame it fails, which you probably already know.

Comment: As of today, does any tidyverse function do the same as `splitstackshape::cSplit`? e.g. `tidyr::cSplitBetter`

Answer (score 2):

This would work for variable number of separators per column, in a single syntax.  Demonstrating on elaborated example.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<- data.frame(a = c("5312,2020,1212", "21,4534"), 
                b = c("345,982,284", "324,234,3425,654"),
                c = c('34,89,89', '87866675'))

df
#>                a                b        c
#> 1 5312,2020,1212      345,982,284 34,89,89
#> 2        21,4534 324,234,3425,654 87866675

reduce(seq_along(df), 
       .init = df, 
       ~ .x %>% separate(names(df)[.y], 
                         sep = ',', 
                         into = paste0(names(df)[.y], '_col_' , seq(1 + max(str_count(df[[.y]], ',')))),
                         fill = 'right'
                         )
       )
#>   a_col_1 a_col_2 a_col_3 b_col_1 b_col_2 b_col_3 b_col_4  c_col_1 c_col_2
#> 1    5312    2020    1212     345     982     284    <NA>       34      89
#> 2      21    4534    <NA>     324     234    3425     654 87866675    <NA>
#>   c_col_3
#> 1      89
#> 2    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same inquiry (learning `tidyverse`), so worked through thus. N.B. that I wanted a solution that doesn't break down, so doesn't rely on knowing colnames.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Create your input:

```
dft <- as_tibble(data.frame(a = c("5312,2020,1212"), b = c("345,982,284")))
df <- as.data.frame(dft)
```

Create a blank tibble to collect output:

```
dft0 <- read_csv("a\na")  
dft0 <- dft0[,-1]
dft00 <- dft0
```

Specify length of the elements to be separated (could be done in-loop, but we know from looking at `dft`); N.B. if you have a better way to name, use that:

```
leng <- 3
```

For-loop version:

```
for(x in 1:dim(df)[2]){
        dataCol <- dft[,x]
        newCols <- paste(colnames(dataCol)[1], paste("col", 1:leng, sep="") , sep="_")

        dft0 <- cbind(dft0,
                    separate(data = dataCol,
                             col = colnames(dataCol)[1],
                             into = newCols,
                             sep = ","))}
```

The messy sapply version:

```
sapp <- sapply(colnames(df),function(ff){
                            separate(as_tibble(df[,ff]),
                                     "value",
                                     letters[1:leng],
                                     sep=",")})

dft00 <- as_tibble(do.call(cbind, sapp))

colnames(dft00) <- as.vector(sapply(colnames(sapp),
                             function(sa){
                                      paste(sa,
                                            rownames(sapp),
                                            sep="_")
                                         }))
```