# convert partitioning folder columns to variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to convert data frame like this:

```
mre <- tibble::tribble(
  ~folder3, ~folder2, ~folder1,
    "V3=4",   "V2=1",   "V1=0",
    "V3=5",   "V2=1",   "V1=0",
    "V3=4",   "V2=2",   "V1=0",
    "V3=5",   "V2=2",   "V1=0",
    "V3=4",   "V2=1",   "V1=1",
    "V3=5",   "V2=1",   "V1=1",
    "V3=4",   "V2=2",   "V1=1",
    "V3=5",   "V2=2",   "V1=1"
  )
```

to this:

```
folder3 folder2 folder1 V3  V2  V1
V3=4    V2=1    V1=0    4   1   0
V3=5    V2=1    V1=0    5   1   0
V3=4    V2=2    V1=0    4   2   0
V3=5    V2=2    V1=0    5   2   0
V3=4    V2=1    V1=1    4   1   1
V3=5    V2=1    V1=1    5   1   1
V3=4    V2=2    V1=1    4   2   1
V3=5    V2=2    V1=1    5   2   1
```

Basically extracting the *unique* variable names ("V3, "V2", "V1" here,  but could be any valid names such as "a", "b", c" ) for each `folder?` column as the new column name, and keep the values in place.

I have the following for a single "folder" column by using the first row value:

```
mre %>% 
    tidyr::extract(folder1, into = .$folder1[1] |> word(1, sep="="), "\\S+=(\\d+)", remove = FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to expand to multiple "folders" columns (the number is not fixed). I tried to use `map` following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277610/tidy-method-to-split-multiple-columns-using-tidyrseparate), but could not figure out how to get the variable names from the first row.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am sorry the variable name "V3" coincide with "folder3" in my example.   It could be any arbitrary name, so it need to be extracted from the column value itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `extract`, we may create new columns within `across` itself - `mutate` `across` all the columns (`everything()`), use `str_extract` to get the digits (`\\d+`) that succeeds the `=`, while modifying the column names in `names` with `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mre %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), 
    ~ as.numeric(str_extract(., "(?<=\\=)\\d+")), 
       .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'folder', 'V')}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  folder3 folder2 folder1    V3    V2    V1
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 V3=4    V2=1    V1=0        4     1     0
2 V3=5    V2=1    V1=0        5     1     0
3 V3=4    V2=2    V1=0        4     2     0
4 V3=5    V2=2    V1=0        5     2     0
5 V3=4    V2=1    V1=1        4     1     1
6 V3=5    V2=1    V1=1        5     1     1
7 V3=4    V2=2    V1=1        4     2     1
8 V3=5    V2=2    V1=1        5     2     1
```

---

If the column names needs to extracted from the 'folder' column values, then one option is to reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer`, split the column with `separate_rows`, reshape back to 'wide' with `pivot_wider` and bind the columns with the original data

```
library(tidyr)
mre %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols= starts_with('folder'), names_to = NULL) %>% 
  separate(value, into = c('name', 'value'), sep="\\=", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
  select(-rn) %>% 
  bind_cols(mre, .)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
  folder3 folder2 folder1    V3    V2    V1
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 V3=4    V2=1    V1=0        4     1     0
2 V3=5    V2=1    V1=0        5     1     0
3 V3=4    V2=2    V1=0        4     2     0
4 V3=5    V2=2    V1=0        5     2     0
5 V3=4    V2=1    V1=1        4     1     1
6 V3=5    V2=1    V1=1        5     1     1
7 V3=4    V2=2    V1=1        4     2     1
8 V3=5    V2=2    V1=1        5     2     1
```

Comment: elegant solution with `str_extract` :) Merry Christmas, my friend!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks.  Merry Xmas to you as well!

Comment: Thx for the answers.  Unfortunately the variable names are not always regular like "V3", "V2", "V1".  They need to be extract from the column values.

Comment: Follow your excellent example,  the following works to extract the variable name from the first row: `mre %>%  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(str_remove(., "\\S+=")), .names = "{str_sub(.[1,], 1, 2)}"))`.   However, I could not get a more general regex such as `str_remove(.[1,], "=\\d+")` to work. in the braces.

Comment: @Dong Try the updated soluiton

Comment: @akrun Nice trick using the row number.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option

```
cbind(
  mre,
  unclass(
    xtabs(
      V2 ~ id + factor(V1, levels = unique(V1)),
      do.call(
        rbind,
        Map(function(x) cbind(read.table(text = x, sep = "="), id = seq_along(x)), mre)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
  folder3 folder2 folder1 V3 V2 V1
1    V3=4    V2=1    V1=0  4  1  0
2    V3=5    V2=1    V1=0  5  1  0
3    V3=4    V2=2    V1=0  4  2  0
4    V3=5    V2=2    V1=0  5  2  0
5    V3=4    V2=1    V1=1  4  1  1
6    V3=5    V2=1    V1=1  5  1  1
7    V3=4    V2=2    V1=1  4  2  1
8    V3=5    V2=2    V1=1  5  2  1
```

---

**Code Breakdowns**

- `Map(..., mre)`

```
> Map(function(x) cbind(read.table(text = x, sep = "="), id = seq_along(x)), mre)
$folder3
  V1 V2 id
1 V3  4  1
2 V3  5  2
3 V3  4  3
4 V3  5  4
5 V3  4  5
6 V3  5  6
7 V3  4  7
8 V3  5  8

$folder2
  V1 V2 id
1 V2  1  1
2 V2  1  2
3 V2  2  3
4 V2  2  4
5 V2  1  5
6 V2  1  6
7 V2  2  7
8 V2  2  8

$folder1
  V1 V2 id
1 V1  0  1
2 V1  0  2
3 V1  0  3
4 V1  0  4
5 V1  1  5
6 V1  1  6
7 V1  1  7
8 V1  1  8
```

- `do.call(rbind, ...)`

```
> do.call(
+   rbind,
+   Map(function(x) cbind(read.table(text = x, sep = "="), id = seq_along(x)), mre)
+ )
          V1 V2 id
folder3.1 V3  4  1
folder3.2 V3  5  2
folder3.3 V3  4  3
folder3.4 V3  5  4
folder3.5 V3  4  5
folder3.6 V3  5  6
folder3.7 V3  4  7
folder3.8 V3  5  8
folder2.1 V2  1  1
folder2.2 V2  1  2
folder2.3 V2  2  3
folder2.4 V2  2  4
folder2.5 V2  1  5
folder2.6 V2  1  6
folder2.7 V2  2  7
folder2.8 V2  2  8
folder1.1 V1  0  1
folder1.2 V1  0  2
folder1.3 V1  0  3
folder1.4 V1  0  4
folder1.5 V1  1  5
folder1.6 V1  1  6
folder1.7 V1  1  7
folder1.8 V1  1  8
```

- `xtabs(..., ...)`

```
> xtabs(
+   V2 ~ id + factor(V1, levels = unique(V1)),
+   do.call(
+     rbind,
+     Map(function(x) cbind(read.table(text = x, sep = "="), id = se .... [TRUNCATED]
   factor(V1, levels = unique(V1))
id  V3 V2 V1
  1  4  1  0
  2  5  1  0
  3  4  2  0
  4  5  2  0
  5  4  1  1
  6  5  1  1
  7  4  2  1
  8  5  2  1
```

Comment: Or another option is `mre[paste0("V", 3:1)] <- "dim<-"(as.numeric(sub(".*\\=", "", as.matrix(mre))), dim(mre))`

Comment: @akrun yes, that option seems much shorter than mine. thanks :)

Comment: I think the `type.convert` would be more easier to understand `mre[paste0("V", 3:1)] <- type.convert(sub(".*\\=", "", as.matrix(mre)), as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks.  This works. But it is beyond my understanding at this time. :-(

Comment: @Dong You can see my code breakdowns

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution you could use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

mre %>%
  bind_cols(
    setNames(seq_len(ncol(mre)) %>%
               map_dfc(~ {y <- unname(unlist(mre[.x]))
               as.integer(str_remove(y, "\\w+="))}), paste0("V", 1:ncol(mre)))
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 6
  folder3 folder2 folder1    V1    V2    V3
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 V3=4    V2=1    V1=0        4     1     0
2 V3=5    V2=1    V1=0        5     1     0
3 V3=4    V2=2    V1=0        4     2     0
4 V3=5    V2=2    V1=0        5     2     0
5 V3=4    V2=1    V1=1        4     1     1
6 V3=5    V2=1    V1=1        5     1     1
7 V3=4    V2=2    V1=1        4     2     1
8 V3=5    V2=2    V1=1        5     2     1
```