# Is it possible to do a pivot table with concatenated aggregations with tbl_summary in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, gtsummary

**Problem**

I have a data.frame including 18 parameters measured at 6 timepoints. I would like to display the mean+standard deviation of each parameter according to each timepoint in a pivot table.

**Expected output**

An example table, which includes only two parameters and two timepoints (dput given below) for the sake of brevity:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left;"> param </th>
      <th style="text-align:left;"> T0 </th>
      <th style="text-align:left;"> T1 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> P1 </td>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> 0.08±0.62 </td>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> 0.21±0.28 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> P2 </td>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> 27.52±23.28 </td>
      <td style="text-align:left;"> 28.46±25.74 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**What I tried**

I failed with `gtsummary`, `dt`, `group_by` statements etc. So I present how I got it manually:

1. selected only the required columns:

`select(starts_with("T")) %>% select(!matches("diff"))`

2. separated timepoint and params:

`tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), cols_vary = "slowest", names_to = c("time", "param"), names_sep = "_")`

3. used a function to compute the median(IQR) or mean±standard deviation accordingly and display as string:

```
custom_aggr <- function(x) {
  s <- shapiro.test(x)
  if(s$p.value < 0.05) {
    paste0(round(median(x, na.rm = T), 2), " (", 
           round(quantile(x, na.rm = T)[2][[1]], 2), "-",
           round(quantile(x, na.rm = T)[4][[1]], 2), ")")
  } else {
    paste0(round(mean(x, na.rm = T), 2), "±", round(sd(x, na.rm = T), 2))    
  }
}
```

4. used it to aggregate (as values_fn accepts only a single, named function) and export to html with kable:

`tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "time", values_from = "value", values_fn = custom_aggr) %>% kable(format = "html)`

The whole process can be applied to the example dput with:

```
example_dput %>% 
    select(starts_with("T")) %>% select(!matches("diff")) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), cols_vary = "slowest", names_to = c("time", "param"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "time", values_from = "value", values_fn = mnsd2) %>%
    kable(format = "html")
```

**Questions**

This is a fairly common case in healthcare-related research, so I expect a more straightforward solution. Yet, I couldn't find a hint in tutorials related to table creation with R, of which the most helpful was the [`gtsummary`](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html). I prefer a solution with gtsummary, which works well with `rmarkdown` and exports directly to word or pdf, since I plan to repeat this analysis periodically. That's whay I tagged the question with `gtsummary`.

Also, the real data contains many grouping variables, which will be used to display the data. This and the future need for a stratified display makes me appreciate a functional approach like that of gt_summary.

I would like to know if:

1. beginning with the long format was the wrong choice?
2. I could use tbl_strata to stratify the table according to the levels of `group` variable.

Finally, I admit that I cannot fully appreciate the use cases of libraries lke tidyr or gt_summary. I occasionally encounter difficulties with manipulating tibbles, yet find it more comfortable to work with tidyr. This mix and match approach makes me feel as a script kiddie and may be the source of difficulties/errors in my code.

[Checking so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42464250/664404), I understand that this problem may have several solutions with base R, and other packages. I öay not appreciate that the solution requires use of multiple packages. So I expect answer(s) explaining the general approach, comparing some alternatives as required, and including some example code. Commenting on the inefficiencies/errors on presented code are welcome.

Thank you for reading so far.

**Example as dput**

An example df including one grouping variable `group`, two parameters `P1` and `P2` is given below to work on:

```
structure(list(group = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), T0_P1 = c(0.354515, 
0.400612, 0.22268, 0.356677, -0.36244, 0.0749541, 0.654674, 0.410779, 
0.282992, 0.279816, 0.359564, 0.498958, 0.207068, 0.538793, -0.791641, 
0.324721, 0.566456, 0.423489, 0.400608, -0.233297, 0.68386, -0.28549, 
-0.291538, 0.516093, 0.143584, 0.231018, 0.468302, 0.0280513, 
0.52974, 0.475668, -0.038977, 0.535264, 0.420121, 0.343218, 0.308243, 
0.10415, 0.017395, 0.548448, 0.0740497, -1.0745, -0.087471, 0.294959, 
0.282871, -2.08282, -2.68453, 0.283177, 0.200626, 0.0388438, 
0.432551, -0.861437, -0.174149, -0.120327, 0.110401), T1_P1 = c(0.370035, 
0.408102, 0.249126, 0.381831, -0.505082, 0.0521383, 0.624644, 
0.374959, 0.172251, 0.140744, 0.34101, 0.424967, 0.174693, 0.115618, 
-0.367998, 0.385345, 0.603818, 0.382661, 0.248948, 0.197852, 
0.694853, -0.212129, -0.129636, 0.513091, 0.0707203, 0.285887, 
0.478958, 0.632496, 0.44714, 0.485816, -0.103302, 0.492024, 0.46066, 
0.365897, 0.290883, 0.0913257, -0.00347047, 0.3081, 0.161523, 
-0.018373, -0.0656219, -0.326731, 0.204379, 0.0954256, 0.40172, 
0.240711, 0.432768, 0.295718, 0.108598, 0.045233, -0.49056, -0.0479581, 
0.228132), T1.T0.diff_P1 = c(4, 2, 12, 7, 39, -30, -5, -9, -39, 
-50, -5, -15, -16, -79, -54, 19, 7, -10, -38, -185, 2, -26, -56, 
-1, -51, 24, 2, 2155, -16, 2, 165, -8, 10, 7, -6, -12, -120, 
-44, 118, -98, -25, -211, -28, -105, -115, -15, 116, 661, -75, 
-105, 182, -60, 107), T2_P1 = c(0.373786, 0.395853, 0.134041, 
0.378412, -0.415208, 0.143939, 0.582672, 0.386103, 0.215891, 
-0.274945, 0.279119, 0.438118, 0.234042, 0.34044, -0.573318, 
0.456852, 0.604797, 0.336034, 0.450904, 0.287317, 0.680436, -0.409743, 
-0.0853578, 0.562901, 0.066638, 0.371619, 0.52145, 0.548569, 
0.514376, 0.479195, 0.053544, 0.177107, 0.35743, 0.422869, 0.331834, 
0.146896, -0.0388651, 0.36162, 0.12057, 0.00685142, -0.000308817, 
-0.208294, 0.290837, 0.154187, 0.446681, 0.233519, 0.117889, 
0.254841, 0.0637857, 0.143729, -0.206059, -0.0150699, -0.219658
), T2.T0.diff_P1 = c(5, -1, -40, 6, 15, 92, -11, -6, -24, -198, 
-22, -12, 13, -37, -28, 41, 7, -21, 13, -223, -1, 44, -71, 9, 
-54, 61, 11, 1856, -3, 1, -237, -67, -15, 23, 8, 41, -323, -34, 
63, -101, -100, -171, 3, -107, -117, -18, -41, 556, -85, -117, 
18, -87, -299), T2.T1.diff_P1 = c(1, -3, -46, -1, -18, 176, 
-7, 3, 25, -295, -18, 3, 34, 194, 56, 19, 0, -12, 81, 45, -2, 
93, -34, 10, -6, 30, 9, -13, 15, -1, -152, -64, -22, 16, 14, 
61, 1020, 17, -25, -137, -100, -36, 42, 62, 11, -3, -73, -14, 
-41, 218, -58, -69, -196), T3_P1 = c(-0.108073, -0.157872, 0.124176, 
0.235193, 0.19941, -0.0932395, 0.264204, 0.0910636, -0.197725, 
0.0419729, -0.393531, 0.116635, 0.121932, 0.585601, -0.412341, 
0.238735, 0.380094, 0.249455, 0.339111, 0.00476125, 0.514552, 
-0.703535, 0.345998, 0.110932, -0.7302, -0.113644, 0.369359, 
0.266292, 0.526663, 0.0106685, -1.01393, -2.39016, -0.653869, 
0.0979844, 0.0634867, 0.0336409, -0.284115, 0.205695, 0.144771, 
0.0072521, -0.182956, -0.165441, 0.227927, 0.00188442, 0.4398, 
0.160438, 0.451799, -0.476955, 0.075239, 0.088576, -0.347784, 
0.136475, -0.213508), T3.T0.diff_P1 = c(-130, -139, -44, -34, 
-155, -224, -60, -78, -170, -85, -209, -77, -41, 9, -48, -26, 
-33, -41, -15, -102, -25, 146, -219, -79, -609, -149, -21, 849, 
-1, -98, 2501, -547, -256, -71, -79, -68, -1733, -62, 96, -101, 
109, -156, -19, -100, -116, -43, 125, -1328, -83, -110, 100, 
-213, -293), T3.T1.diff_P1 = c(-129, -139, -50, -38, -139, -279, 
-58, -76, -215, -70, -215, -73, -30, 406, 12, -38, -37, -35, 
36, -98, -26, 232, -367, -78, -1133, -140, -23, -58, 18, -98, 
882, -586, -242, -73, -78, -63, 8087, -33, -10, -139, 179, -49, 
12, -98, 9, -33, 4, -261, -31, 96, -29, -385, -194), T4_P1 = c(-0.127339, 
0.234353, 0.0615958, 0.174939, 0.249978, -0.428429, 0.276876, 
0.238878, -0.0508291, -0.11582, -0.25588, 0.35472, 0.114993, 
0.544118, -0.2078, -0.141583, 0.501062, -0.0577436, 0.449832, 
-0.819736, 0.536002, -0.671793, 0.449196, 0.166851, -0.848327, 
-0.148966, 0.608949, 0.299139, 0.358773, -0.122672, -0.789994, 
-0.470871, -0.337386, 0.363851, 0.135002, -0.2105, -0.355363, 
0.211093, 0.0403827, -0.401496, -0.163691, 0.161768, 0.0766178, 
-0.19001, 0.44916, 0.22669, 0.400209, -0.221847, 0.409649, -0.626259, 
-0.841326, 0.197649, -0.365613), T4.T0.diff_P1 = c(-136, -42, 
-72, -51, -169, -672, -58, -42, -118, -141, -171, -29, -44, 1, 
-74, -144, -12, -114, 12, 251, -22, 135, -254, -68, -691, -164, 
30, 966, -32, -126, 1927, -188, -180, 6, -56, -302, -2143, -62, 
-45, -63, 87, -45, -73, -91, -117, -20, 99, -671, -5, -27, 383, 
-264, -431), T4.T1.diff_P1 = c(-134, -43, -75, -54, -149, -922, 
-56, -36, -130, -182, -175, -17, -34, 371, -44, -137, -17, -115, 
81, -514, -23, 217, -447, -67, -1300, -152, 27, -53, -20, -125, 
665, -196, -173, -1, -54, -330, 10140, -31, -75, 2085, 149, -150, 
-63, -299, 12, -6, -8, -175, 277, -1485, 72, -512, -260), T5_P1 = c(-0.1898, 
0.278567, 0.191452, 0.242484, 0.188506, -0.254942, 0.123944, 
0.121264, -0.058461, -0.0706581, -0.223103, 0.369762, 0.154631, 
0.56503, -0.336153, -0.152756, 0.405927, -0.0312427, 0.102258, 
-1.10958, 0.533744, -0.507479, -0.255318, 0.472308, -0.839511, 
-0.164691, 0.511855, -0.0619669, 0.385496, -0.0389004, -0.143956, 
0.0928928, -0.436918, 0.419153, 0.234921, -0.161249, -0.236711, 
0.121568, 0.109438, -0.150289, -0.0742779, 0.332437, 0.274052, 
-0.285785, 0.492551, 0.304347, 0.473602, -0.091301, -0.0833264, 
-0.492741, 0.0980397, 0.28639, -0.122452), T5.T0.diff_P1 = c(-154, 
-30, -14, -32, -152, -440, -81, -70, -121, -125, -162, -26, -25, 
5, -58, -147, -28, -107, -74, 376, -22, 78, -12, -8, -685, -171, 
9, -321, -27, -108, 269, -83, -204, 22, -24, -255, -1461, -78, 
48, -86, -15, 13, -3, -86, -118, 7, 136, -335, -119, -43, -156, 
-338, -211), T5.T1.diff_P1 = c(-151, -32, -23, -36, -137, -589, 
-80, -68, -134, -150, -165, -13, -11, 389, -9, -140, -33, -108, 
-59, -661, -23, 139, 97, -8, -1287, -158, 7, -110, -14, -108, 
39, -81, -195, 15, -19, -277, 6721, -61, -32, 718, 13, -202, 
34, -399, 23, 26, 9, -131, -177, -1189, -120, -697, -154), T6_P1 = c(0.0704855, 
0.126056, -0.041206, -0.50256, -0.0191214, 0.0130739, -0.0660002, 
-0.352739, -0.404444, -0.00161666, 0.0881695, 0.501725, 0.182178, 
0.201283, -0.321061, -0.496934, 0.430376, 0.18756, 0.469647, 
-0.297791, 0.325876, -0.949504, 0.202842, 0.451688, -0.5095, 
0.111856, -0.129408, 0.357865, 0.292238, 0.143681, -0.465477, 
-0.447798, -0.166457, 0.170199, -0.106613, 0.11888, -0.0224689, 
0.290059, -1.02956, 0.0534638, -0.876711, 0.0234375, -0.208117, 
0.121276, -0.10558, -3.63428, -0.178923, -0.27206, -1.187, -0.0671986, 
-0.185629, -0.102337, 0.135412), T0_P2 = c(23.4767, 80.6425, 
27.6929, 36.3399, 0.222854, 15.4059, 16.3445, 10.3642, 60.1418, 
10.7158, 73.6641, 74.3803, 82.1072, 28.709, 19.5041, 22.0872, 
24.0681, 10.1122, 17.4177, 17.5524, 23.7382, 14.7304, 94.7995, 
16.6482, 30.4161, 23.0676, 14.3303, 47.4505, 34.8889, 12.017, 
17.7335, 0, 21.6478, 13.8952, 12.9003, 17.1954, 22.6989, 99.8425, 
20.3926, 4.82337, 29.8876, 15.7117, 18.5338, 33.1752, 14.0226, 
15.0854, 8.91286, 26.1874, 23.1092, 35.0972, 5.55667, 11.1803, 
27.9371), T1_P2 = c(16.1512, 16.0162, 25.7443, 25.5485, 20.5682, 
19.2128, 13.2216, 60.5308, 50.5352, 17.9931, 10.7115, 93.1466, 
77.2653, 13.0037, 20.4135, 10.9121, 22.838, 75.1338, 31.0509, 
15.826, 84.0741, 13.0837, 19.1441, 61.3631, 13.0631, 32.1478, 
83.8708, 0, 10.8444, 40.9282, 18.9858, 0, 97.1279, 10.1327, 61.5105, 
23.271, 21.4968, 75.2181, 15.4974, 13.6953, 10.9891, 17.2444, 
14.447, 25.7276, 11.0123, 7.84029, 12.0358, 14.6238, 26.1094, 
19.4256, 4.30366, 4.01792, 9.30375), T1.T0.diff_P2 = c(-31, 
-80, -7, -30, 9129, 25, -19, 484, -16, 68, -85, 25, -6, -55, 
5, -51, -5, 643, 78, -10, 254, -11, -80, 269, -57, 39, 485, -100, 
-69, 241, 7, NaN, 349, -27, 377, 35, -5, -25, -24, 184, -63, 
10, -22, -22, -21, -48, 35, -44, 13, -45, -23, -64, -67), T2_P2 = c(17.6024, 
13.7435, 31.066, 36.6922, 17.9928, 23.0723, 61.4986, 90.0946, 
49.7064, 18.4268, 93.6249, 64.6212, 66.0091, 51.8095, 85.8795, 
17.8472, 20.5687, 10.1429, 17.3647, 24.6992, 20.6315, 57.3102, 
72.0594, 64.146, 10.0122, 80.8444, 12.5641, 91.9954, 54.9446, 
43.0989, 17.8794, 13.4608, 11.6372, 58.2568, 38.3219, 22.9037, 
11.2806, 15.4506, 10.765, 12.843, 9.43461, 5.55588, 10.5876, 
25.9979, 20.3327, 9.23773, 10.9801, 82.6116, 14.2446, 25.8306, 
10.359, 7.52712, 18.3046), T2.T0.diff_P2 = c(-25, -83, 12, 1, 
7974, 50, 276, 769, -17, 72, 27, -13, -20, 80, 340, -19, -15, 
0, 0, 41, -13, 289, -24, 285, -67, 250, -12, 94, 57, 259, 1, 
Inf, -46, 319, 197, 33, -50, -85, -47, 166, -68, -65, -43, -22, 
45, -39, 23, 215, -38, -26, 86, -33, -34), T2.T1.diff_P2 = c(9, 
-14, 21, 44, -13, 20, 365, 49, -2, 2, 774, -31, -15, 298, 321, 
64, -10, -87, -44, 56, -75, 338, 276, 5, -23, 151, -85, Inf, 
407, 5, -6, Inf, -88, 475, -38, -2, -48, -79, -31, -6, -14, -68, 
-27, 1, 85, 18, -9, 465, -45, 33, 141, 87, 97), T3_P2 = c(68.731, 
12.7383, 25.7426, 30.4209, 95.1241, 30.5427, 69.711, 95.4164, 
66.3215, 12.0129, 79.4669, 13.884, 11.3739, 39.1618, 31.8607, 
11.3097, 10.465, 45.7652, 10.2818, 25.492, 35.3997, 44.1852, 
28.2852, 11.1805, 69.4717, 77.7511, 10.573, 14.9569, 86.5404, 
34.5778, 30.6023, 89.6231, 16.3404, 32.2442, 67.5567, 15.6465, 
17.3722, 30.3812, 10.2457, 4.68845, 13.1288, 10.1949, 8.64307, 
5.27611, 22.0138, 10.4523, 7.4947, 77.573, 14.8642, 19.6778, 
15.5668, 3.56341, 22.285), T3.T0.diff_P2 = c(193, -84, -7, -16, 
42584, 98, 327, 821, 10, 12, 8, -81, -86, 36, 63, -49, -57, 353, 
-41, 45, 49, 200, -70, -33, 128, 237, -26, -68, 148, 188, 73, 
Inf, -25, 132, 424, -9, -23, -70, -50, -3, -56, -35, -53, -84, 
57, -31, -16, 196, -36, -44, 180, -68, -20), T3.T1.diff_P2 = c(326, 
-20, 0, 19, 362, 59, 427, 58, 31, -33, 642, -85, -85, 201, 56, 
4, -54, -39, -67, 61, -58, 238, 48, -82, 432, 142, -87, Inf, 
698, -16, 61, Inf, -83, 218, 10, -33, -19, -60, -34, -66, 19, 
-41, -40, -79, 100, 33, -38, 430, -43, 1, 262, -11, 140), T4_P2 = c(14.0407, 
86.8672, 11.4711, 30.0838, 67.8631, 81.9849, 72.5374, 83.0472, 
65.794, 85.05, 10.5096, 74.2366, 10.8808, 53.6499, 13.5859, 99.9067, 
12.1605, 13.9899, 40.1762, 20.1221, 16.0165, 38.9638, 11.5921, 
75.9692, 10.5741, 13.1628, 67.1616, 11.6427, 10.1465, 10.3222, 
48.7381, 77.0429, 32.6667, 16.3706, 11.0336, 11.8518, 18.4726, 
10.0398, 3.48196, 8.6861, 6.32977, 18.1642, 18.7497, 12.7896, 
17.9789, 15.0961, 10.5745, 19.8159, 22.8705, 5.8275, 16.8047, 
3.72111, 8.86339), T4.T0.diff_P2 = c(-40, 8, -59, -17, 30352, 
432, 344, 701, 9, 694, -86, 0, -87, 87, -30, 352, -49, 38, 131, 
15, -33, 165, -88, 356, -65, -43, 369, -75, -71, -14, 175, Inf, 
51, 18, -14, -31, -19, -90, -83, 80, -79, 16, 1, -61, 28, 0, 
19, -24, -1, -83, 202, -67, -68), T4.T1.diff_P2 = c(-13, 442, 
-55, 18, 230, 327, 449, 37, 30, 373, -2, -20, -86, 313, -33, 
816, -47, -81, 29, 27, -81, 198, -39, 24, -19, -59, -20, Inf, 
-6, -75, 157, Inf, -66, 62, -82, -49, -14, -87, -78, -37, -42, 
5, 30, -50, 63, 93, -12, 36, -12, -70, 290, -7, -5), T5_P2 = c(10.5461, 
29.1796, 88.1755, 38.6234, 22.0569, 10.001, 13.4991, 14.8506, 
19.519, 95.617, 17.8181, 84.2492, 10.7215, 88.9674, 76.4191, 
45.19, 10.8317, 31.8107, 24.7983, 55.9251, 16.4832, 43.3698, 
22.1386, 18.002, 79.2035, 12.6423, 85.4316, 32.1691, 75.6754, 
53.5464, 17.2313, 15.1174, 59.3047, 12.0834, 82.7295, 81.1334, 
10.7536, 30.5454, 12.4223, 9.50655, 5.0372, 8.15472, 10.8593, 
6.14378, 5.62171, 6.21806, 4.05756, 12.0619, 21.1074, 12.9207, 
13.4733, 32.445, 20.8236), T5.T0.diff_P2 = c(-55, -64, 218, 
6, 9797, -35, -17, 43, -68, 792, -76, 13, -87, 210, 292, 105, 
-55, 215, 42, 219, -31, 194, -77, 8, 160, -45, 496, -32, 117, 
346, -3, Inf, 174, -13, 541, 372, -53, -69, -39, 97, -83, -48, 
-41, -81, -60, -59, -54, -54, -9, -63, 142, 190, -25), T5.T1.diff_P2 = c(-35, 
82, 243, 51, 7, -48, 2, -75, -61, 431, 66, -10, -86, 584, 274, 
314, -53, -58, -20, 253, -80, 231, 16, -71, 506, -61, 2, Inf, 
598, 31, -9, Inf, -39, 19, 34, 249, -50, -59, -20, -31, -54, 
-53, -25, -76, -49, -21, -66, -18, -19, -33, 213, 708, 124), 
    T6_P2 = c(19.4431, 18.3498, 36.6816, 20.8788, 20.7658, 22.2604, 
    60.7024, 10.4609, 98.5593, 62.8739, 71.6437, 22.755, 97.5644, 
    98.5916, 93.0426, 90.9254, 72.4049, 86.6857, 13.1171, 28.2106, 
    28.0355, 54.2341, 10.2572, 12.291, 56.9864, 10.5199, 68.7879, 
    32.782, 61.1115, 16.1887, 29.1698, 66.4892, 23.1343, 10.191, 
    20.0709, 38.6514, 91.7475, 91.9235, 5.50988, 22.1358, 22.3813, 
    12.6712, 8.06821, 22.8411, 15.0756, 6.79443, 26.9108, 18.2863, 
    9.69334, 4.18761, 22.297, 24.9186, 48.9786)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
53L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use gtsummary, you'll need your data in long format with one line per person per timepoint. See below

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# get data into one line per person, per timepoint
df_restrucutre <-
  df |> 
  select(group, matches("^T[0-9]_")) |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(id, group),
    names_to = "time_param"
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    timepoint = word(time_param, 1L, sep = "_"),
    param = word(time_param, 2L, sep = "_")
  ) |> 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(id, group, timepoint),
    names_from = param, 
    values_from = value
  )

df_restrucutre |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = timepoint,
    include = starts_with("P"),
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± {sd}",
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2
  ) |> 
  # convert to kable so the table will display on stackoverflow
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **T0**, N = 53 | **T1**, N = 53 | **T2**, N = 53 | **T3**, N = 53 | **T4**, N = 53 | **T5**, N = 53 | **T6**, N = 53 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 0.08 ± 0.62 | 0.21 ± 0.28 | 0.21 ± 0.28 | -0.03 ± 0.47 | -0.01 ± 0.39 | 0.02 ± 0.34 | -0.15 ± 0.61 |
| P2 | 27.52 ± 23.28 | 28.46 ± 25.74 | 33.66 ± 26.67 | 32.91 ± 27.28 | 30.74 ± 28.08 | 32.40 ± 28.18 | 38.48 ± 29.91 |

<sup>Created on 2023-04-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the library as well. The code helped me to get both summary and stratified tables. But tbl_strata outputs two separate tables with group = 0 and group = 1, whereas tbl_strata2 outputs the two on the same page, side by side. But I don't get one like "Example 1" on the page "https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html".  How can I get  T_* params in place of grades, and group in place of drugs or vice versa?

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is....the code in the examples is run on my machine without error, then it's later run on 12 different systems, again, without error.  You should make a separate post about your issue. Please include a _minimal reproducible example_ with your post.

Comment: Ok, I'll try without loading other library/packages. Sorry about the dput. Apparently forgot to remove T3-T6.